# Angular E2E tests - Protractor-Cucumber-Framework creating hundreds of strange cache files

Tags: angular, typescript, selenium, protractor, cucumber

In an `Angular` project, we're using the `Protractor-Cucumber-Framework` for our `E2E tests`. After running all my E2E tests, not only does it update a `results.json` and `results.xml` file (this seems normal to me), but it also generates hundreds of cryptic, un-openable cache files under a new `null` folder (see attached screenshot). There are literally almost 1000 of these new files. Is this normal, and can anyone tell me what these are for and how to prevent this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've disabled these files being created on every test run by commenting out a line `'--disk-cache-dir=null',` in the `chromeOptions` property of `protractor.conf.js`:

```
chromeOptions: {
  prefs: {
    'plugins.always_open_pdf_externally': true,
    download: {
      directory_upgrade: true,
      prompt_for_download: false,
      default_directory: downloadsPath,
    },
  },
  args: [
    '--no-sandbox',
    '--test-type=browser',
    '--disable-gpu',
    '--log-level=1',
    '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
    // '--disk-cache-dir=null',
  ],
},
```